# scroll asp:CheckBoxList using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to sroll asp:CheckBoxList item to top  of list automatically
 *(if enter value on textbox like name (or) item of type item text on screen)*
using java script

*(items added from code behind)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question. But if to want to scroll using javascript then do this

```
  window.scrollTo(300, 500);
```

See also http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_scrollto2

Comment: Thanks !! ,  scrollTo used for div of that checkbox list.